# How to add string after specific character in PHP

Tags: php

I am working with php. I have some dynamic string. Now I want to add some number after some string. Like, I have a string `this is me (1)`. Now I want to add `-7` after `1`. So that string should be print like this `this is me (1-7)`.
I have done this properly by using `substr_replace`. like this

```
substr_replace('this is me (1)','-59',-1,-1)
```

Now if there is more than one number like this `this is me(2,3,1)`. I want to add `-7` after each number. like this one `this is me(2-7,3-7,1-7).`

Please help. TIA

Comment: You might want to take a look at [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if there is a good way to do this in one or two lines, but the solution I came up with looks something like this:

```
$subject = "this is me (2,3,1)";

if (preg_match('[(?<text>.*)\((?<numbers>[0-9,]+)\)]', $subject, $matches)) {
  $numbers = explode(",", $matches['numbers']);
  $numbers = array_map(function($item) {
      return $item.'-7';
  }, $numbers);

  echo $matches['text'].'('.implode(",", $numbers).')';
}
```

What happens here is the following:

1. `preg_match` checks whether the text is in our desired format
2. We generate an array from our captured named group `numbers` with `explode`
3. We add our "Magic Value" (-7) to every array element
4. We're joining the text back together

Comment: Wow. great. You solved my problem . Thank you so much .